# Is there is a way to restrict the number of branches created by the user in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

We have notice some repositories have many benches, some of them more than 1000.
Is there is a way to restrict the number of branches created by the user, so we can control the number of branches created?

Bitbucket version: 6.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, this functionality isn't currently available in the product. However, there is an open feature request for this here:
[Restrict Git branch creation](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-9870?error=login_required&error_description=Login%20required&state=0c607291-e173-4097-bdb0-d4aa0d156bda)